# Can "in" be replaced by "with"?

Tags: phrases, prepositions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Covered with” vs “covered in” vs “covered by”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60805/covered-with-vs-covered-in-vs-covered-by)

From J.K. Rowling’s [*Harry Potter and the Philosopher’s Stone* (June 1997)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Philosopher's_Stone):

> He bent down and pulled his wand out of the troll’s nose. It was
>   covered **in** what looked like lumpy grey glue. ‘Urgh — troll
>   bogies.’

Or in its shamelessly bowdlerized version, [*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer’s Stone* (October 1997)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Philosopher's_Stone#U.S._publication_and_reception), ‘translated’ from the original English for the American mass-market audience:

> He bent down and pulled his wand out of the troll’s nose. It was
>   covered **in** what looked like lumpy gray glue. “Urgh — troll
>   boogers.”

From [Colin Fine’s explanation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60805/covered-with-vs-covered-in-vs-covered-by), I can picture the troll’s boogers widespread over the wand, not hiding it. In the example, can “in” be replaced by “with” keeping the same meaning in the reply?

---

[image: Troll Bogies card, with quotation]

Comment: Yes, _with_ can replace _in_ without changing the meaning in this sentence.

Comment: In general, 'in' and 'with' are definitely __not__ interchangeable. But in the duplicate question, it shows that often 'covered with' and 'covered in' can be.

Comment: Wait...'bowdlerized'? There were vulgarities in the English version replaced with euphemisms or entirely ignored in the American version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my ear, "covered with" suggests that it was done deliberately and beneficently.  "She covered him with a blanket", "The turtle eggs were covered with sand".

"Covered in" suggests that it was an sloppy accident.  "I'm covered in mud!"

Comment: Well, to be honest, nobody says "I'm covered with mud!" But you can say "He's all covered with mud" and that seems pretty synonymous to using in

Comment: @Nile: [Here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he's+covered+with+mud%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) and [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he+is+covered+with+mud%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are over 500 written instances of *"he's/he is covered with mud"*, and there are nearly as many for *I* and *she*. There's no reason to suppose interpolating *all* makes it any more "grammatical" (it's just a word children are more likely to use than *completely*).

Answer (score 1):

To me the two seem pretty much synonymous. Aside from some idiomatic usages, *cover with* seems to be much more common in all cases.