# "Encapsulated by" vs. "encapsulated in" vs. "encapsulated with"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

I am writing some text wherein I have to mean "wrapped with double quotes". Would any of the following expressions be correct?

> - encapsulated **with** double quotes
> - encapsulated **in** double quotes
> - encapsulated **by** double quotes

Or is there another way to phrase this?

Comment: I would just say a double-quoted string, or one delimited by double quotes, where delimited of course means surrounded or enclosed, not just separated or split on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Covered with" vs. "covered in" vs. "covered by"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60805/covered-with-vs-covered-in-vs-covered-by)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the term *encapsulated* in this scenario seems a bit too [grandiloquent](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/grandiloquent?q=grandiloquent).

I would suggest you to use, instead, a more common expression like *[enclosed](http://books.google.com/books?id=H4q1t-jAcBIC&pg=PA113&dq=enclosed+in+double+quotes&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nL_pULG-HcThiwK48IGgAg&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=enclosed%20in%20double%20quotes&f=false) in double quotes*. But if you insist on using *encapsulated*, personally I would prefer

> encapsulated in double quotes

as when you use "*encapsulated in double quotes*", it is literally **encapsulated in 
" "**.

Comment: Java, C# or C++ programmers are too used to the term "encapsulated" that we don't find it "grandiloquent" at all to use it under non-programming contexts.

Answer (score 1):

You might say *enclosed in* or *enclosed by* double quotes.
*[Enclosed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enclosed#Adjective)* has an applicable sense of  “fenced in or surrounded”.  *[Encapsulated](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/encapsulate#English)*, on the other hand, from its sense of something covered as in a capsule, seems to me inappropriate for the linear structure of an opening quotes/text/closing quotes structure.  If you intend a technical meaning of encapsulated (such as putting text into a standard form) you might consider *[encase](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/encase#Verb)* as an alternative to *encapsulate* or *enclose*.

If you merely mean to say that double quotes have been added, perhaps use none of the above and instead try a phrase like “with double quotes added” or a sentence like “Double quotes were added.”

Answer (score 0):

I would not use *encapsulated* at all.

[***marked***](http://books.google.com/books?id=9_LsfbKqUW8C&pg=PA19&dq=%22marked+in+double%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=v7vpUPBB6pzZBYv8gaAB&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22marked%20in%20double%22&f=false) *in double quotations* is how I've seen it worded.