# Which is the correct option: "a jungle covered in snow" or "a jungle covered with snow"?

Tags: prepositions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Covered with” vs “covered in” vs “covered by”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60805/covered-with-vs-covered-in-vs-covered-by)

Which is the correct option: "a jungle covered in snow" or "a jungle covered with snow"? If both are possible what is the difference in meaning?

Comment: How about just "a snow-covered jungle"? It shouldn't matter. After all, it doesn't snow in the jungle, only in the mountains that may tower above the jungle. Jungles are tropical. I live in the tropics. While it does snow high up on Taiwan's tits, we're talking at 3500-4000 meters, not the jungles below.

Comment: Why should only one be correct?

Answer (score 1):

There’s little difference in meaning, but each sees the scene from a slightly different aspect. *Covered by snow* emphasises the fact that it was snow that covered the jungle, while *covered in snow* describes the result of what the snow did.

Comment: This feels like a distinction without a difference.

Comment: @Robusto. Really? I rather thought it was a difference without a distinction.

Comment: What may be difference or distinction between difference and distinction?

Comment: @Kris. It's the same as the contrast or variation between dissimilarity and divergence.