# 'In the ranks' OR 'With the ranks'

Tags: phrases, expressions, prepositions

Which of the following two phrases is correct?

> I'd put him right there **in** the ranks of the best anthropologists out there.

**OR**

> I'd put him right there **with** the ranks of the best anthropologists out there.

Comment: I think it should be 'in' because of a category.

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to context and what you're trying to convey. Based off [J.R.'s answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/60818/96265) to a related question, you'd probably want to use **in** rather than **with**, for this specific sentence.

Comment: I’m inclined to agree that **in** is better than **with** for this context. But what part of [J.R.’s answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/60805/26083#60818) are you referring to (to support your answer)?

Comment: There's not a specific example from JR's answer that definitively maps 1:1 with this question, but I believe the framing of the examples can help the reader infer the correct usage when considering the abstract placement of the entities within the sentence. _**him**_ is being placed within a cadre of top professionals per the sentence's intent. Being _**in**_ / _**within**_ their ranks makes more sense than being _**with**_ them. Being _**with**_ them can be fairly open-ended (supporters, partners, etc.) whereas being _**in**_ their ranks makes the context quite specific.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a "correct" or "incorrect" here. I can offer reasons I think **in** differs from **with**.
The military has been somewhat conservative with the use of "rank". And, an analogy from the military might help.

> Joe is part of the NPCC (National Patineer Commando Corps). He is an
>   elite soldier, mounted on ice skates. He is **in** the NPCC. He serves
>   **in** the NPCC.
>
> Bill serves **in** the NSS (National Signals Service). He is a
>   radioman. The NSS is not thought of as "elite".

For 3 weeks one December, Bill  sets up radio relays within the operational area of a NPCC unit.

> Bill serves for 3 weeks **with** the NPCC.  However, Bill is still **in** the NSS. He is not **in** the NPCC.

If I want maximum positive effect, I will place someone **in** the ranks of a venerated group. Placing that person **with** the ranks of such a venerated group does not seem as positive to me as placing **in**.

I would chose **in** so there would be no doubt that I think the person belongs **in** the ranks of the best. Here, **with** just does not convey the sense of *belonging* that **in** does.

.